# Error trying to export in TIFF format using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to export a file in TIFF format but gives the following error:
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected: Image. Actual: ImageCollection.

This is my script:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CDR/AVHRR/NDVI/V4')
    .filterDate('2008-04-01', '2008-07-01');

var median = collection.median();

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/julianabelmiro18/Tailandia');

var clipped = median.clipToCollection(fc);

Map.centerObject(fc, 9)
var visParams = {bands: ['NDVI'], min:-1000.0, max:5000.0,palette: [
    'ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'fcd163', 'c6ca02', '22cc04', '99b718', '207401',
    '012e01'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(clipped, visParams, 'clipped composite');

print (visParams)

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: collection,
  description: 'imageToCOGeoTiffExample',
  scale: 0.0001,
  region: ee.Feature(fc.first()).geometry().bounds(),
  maxPixels:1e13,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to try and export `collection` or did you actually want to export the single image `median`?  Perhaps that a typo in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to export an image collection (multiple images) while you can export only one image. Filter that image collection. Use for example collection.first() to get the first image in that collection. Or try to use clipped as image instead of collection in your export call